# How to swap the z-order of two objects in inkscape

Tags: inkscape, depth

I have two objects A and B in an Inkscape drawing with many other objects. At the moment A lays over B (i.e., A is higher in the *z-ordering* than B). I would like that the z-ordering swaps, that is, that B lays over A.

Because the drawing has many objects, it is burdensome to use the function `Lower Selection` or `Raise Selection`. I would like in one click to swap the z-ordering. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Inkscape (at least from v. *1.01*) there is an *extension* that allows to do fancy reordering actions with selected objects: **Restack**.

Go in the menu bar to *Extensions > Arrange > Restack*, and then on the “Restack” dialog choose the tab *“Based on Z-order”* and the option *“Reverse Z-Order”* in *“Restack Mode”*.

That's it! A lot of time saved.